# Criando coleção de bytes em navegadores antigos através do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, tipagem

Eu queria saber se existe algo como [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) em navegadores antigos (ao mínimo no IE8), um tipo de coleção com elementos que ocupam apenas 1 byte da memória do navegador.

Uma aproximação seria usar *strings*, porém, pelo que eu saiba, os navegadores usam a codificação UTF-16 que usa 2 (ou mais, eu acho) bytes para cada caractere.

No Lua, por exemplo, algo que ajudaria à criar algo como `Uint8Array` seria uma *string* (pois lá, cada caractere de uma *string* é de 8 bits). Porém uma *string* tem que ser recriada para ser modificada, então não acho uma boa ideia.

P.S.: O Cheat Engine (ou alguma ferramenta similar) pode ajudar a ver a memória do navegador. Abaixo há uma lista de bytes fixa criada por uma instância de `U\u{69}nt8Array`.

[image: Memória]

Então, há alguma maneira de fazer isso ao mínimo no IE8, através do JavaScript (ou em combinação ao VBScript)? Os bytes dessa coleção terão que ser modificados ocasionalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript provavelmente não é a linguagem mais adequada para isso. Ela não foi criada pensando em minimizar o uso de memória e flexibilizar seu acesso. Agora estão incluindo um pouco esse tipo de coisa.

O que dá pra fazer, mas é uma tremenda gambiarra, é usar *string* mesmo e colocar dois dados em cada caractere já que o **JS é especificado para usar UTF-16**. Terá que criar uma biblioteca para fazer essa composição e acessar do jeito que quiser. O máximo que vai ter de desperdício é um byte se tiver um número ímpar de elementos.

Dá para fazer com o tipo numérico também, apesar de ser uma composição ligeiramente mais difícil de ser feita. Teria que analisar todas implicações, não sei se é uma ideia tão boa para colocar em um *array* dependendo do *engine* do JS usado.

Dadas as dificuldades, eu diria que é melhor abrir mão disso ou do requisito de funcionar em navegadores antigos.

Comment: Concordo. A minha ideia de fazer isso na linguagem não mais adequada era para transpilar Lua para um tipo de coleção de dados que seriam computados pelo JavaScript, assim se tornando uma transpilação de Lua para JavaScript, sem ter que interpretar Lua novamente no JavaScript. Eu quero isso mais por conta de performance. Porém, se `Uint8Array` não for suportado, eu ainda posso adicionar um polyfill + um aviso (ou algo típico) dizendo que seria melhor usar um navegador atual. Vlw pela resposta.